# Removing string in HTML using .replaceWith in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML Source

```
<td>
<a id="ctl00_link_Link1" href="/Default.aspx?ID=10">Link 1</a>
</td>
<td>|</td>
<td>
<a id="ctl00_link_Link2" href="/Default.aspx?ID=11">Link 2</a>
</td>
```

I need to remove the following string after the document has loaded.

```
<td>|</td>
<td>
<a id="ctl00_link_Link2" href="/Default.aspx?ID=11">Link 2</a>
</td>
```

How can I do this ?

I was able to hide the link 2 by using the below,

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_link_Link2").style.cssText="display:none";
```

But I want to remove the "|" as well. So trying to use the .replaceWith in jquery like the below, but not working..

```
$('<td>|</td><td><a id="ctl00_link_Link2" href="/Default.aspx?ID=11">Link 2</a></td>').replaceWith('');
```

How can i remove the string from HTML source ?

Full TABLE :

```
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td><a class="selected-type" id="ctl00_link_english" href="default.aspx?type=English">English</a></td>
<td>|</td>
<td><a id="ctl00_link_spanish" href="default.aspx?type=Spanish">Spanish</a></td>
<td><div style="width:190px;"></div></td>
<td><a title="Decrease Text Size" onclick="javascript:ts('bottom-section', -1)" id="a_descrease_font_size" href="#"><img src="small_font.png"></a></td>
<td><a title="Reset Text Size" onclick="javascript:ts('bottom-section', 0)" id="a_reset_font_size" href="#"><img src="default_font.png"></a></td>
<td><a title="Increase Text Size" onclick="javascript:ts('bottom-section', 1)" id="a_increase_font_size" href="#"><img src="big_font.png"></a></td>
<td><div style="width:20px;"></div></td>
<td><a id="ctl00_link_Link1" href="/Default.aspx?ID=10">Link 1</a>
</td><td>|</td>
<td><a id="ctl00_link_Link2" href="/Default.aspx?ID=11">Link 2</a></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><div onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_btn_search')" id="ctl00_pnl_search">
<input type="text" id="ctl00_txt_search" name="ctl00$txt_search">
<div style="display:none"><input type="submit" id="ctl00_btn_search" value="" name="ctl00$btn_search"></div> 
</div></td>
<td>
<input type="image" style="border-width:0px;" src="find.png" id="ctl00_imgbtn_search" name="ctl00$imgbtn_search">
</td>
<td><a target="_blank" href="rss.aspx"><img src="rss.png"></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot remove this while the HTML is being generated?

Comment: try `$('table tr').find('td:gt(-2)').remove()`

Comment: can you provide the entire `<table>` ? cause solutions below will most likely break the table html code

Comment: @Reigel Updated the HTML rendered for entire table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
$('#ctl00_link_Link2').closest('td').html('&nbsp;').prev().html('&nbsp;')
```

Answer (score 2):

<del>You can just use `.replace()` on the HTML of the element.</del>

```
$('.table').html(function(index, html){
  return html.replace('<td>|</td><td><a id="ctl00_link_Link2" href="/Default.aspx?ID=11">Link 2</a></td>', '');
});
```

**EDIT**

My above answer would only work with white space exactly right. Definitely not likely.

I went with this instead.

```
$('table').find('td:gt(0)').remove();
```

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/IkEvofUt/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It depends on where you're putting the script. If you're putting it right before the `</body>` no. If it's in the `<head>` yes.

Comment: The script comes before the body. I have not used document.ready, but used the same script you have given. But still I could see the part which needs to be hided.

Comment: The function is not invoked.

Comment: I just tried to set up a demo and noticed an error in my logic. The white space makes this a bad way to approach it. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I dont think we can go this approach. Given the HTML in JSBIN, yes there is not problem and it works. But this is the sample i have given i my question. And the page has a lot more in HTML and a lot of tr and td in the table we are trying to remove a particular string. When I used your latest script, it removes a lot of HTML stuffs in my page. confused..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the `|`

```
$('.table').html(function(index, html){
  return html.replace('|','');
})
```

Comment: This wouldn't replace `|` since the `|` is special in regex. This would try to replace nothing or nothing. If you just want to replace the `|` you can just quote it, no reason for a regex here.